# How to deploy SQL Database in Bitbucket pipeline to Azure

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, bitbucket-pipelines

Asking for an opinion or direction on the current problem.

We are using bitbucket pipeline to deploy ci/cd web applications to Azure. Now what is remaining - the database, also being hosted on Azure.

From my research - everything on SQL Database Projects deployments usually utilizes Azure DevOps pipelines (connects to github repo, allows plural environments, has a built-in SqlAgent allows deploy SQL db to the target server via dacpac file. It allows CI with every check-in, every time you push changes. Nice!

But what if can not (for some reason) use Azure DevOps and have to utilize **Bitbucket pipelines** instead. is that possible? how? via scripting? a tool? to call in the command line? Any help - highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that in Azure DevOps it is easier to deploy (Azure) SQL Database, as Azure DevOps offers many tasks (including 3rd party custom tasks you can find in Microsoft MarketPlace).
However, no matter what tool will you use, you should be able to do the same, knowing the concept of deployment of a specific service.
I don't know BitBucket very well, but I bet the product has the capability to execute some commands, including PowerShell commands as well. If so, you must do 2 steps in your pipeline to publish Azure SQL database:
1) Create server and (empty) database - perhaps BitBucket offers some task for creating services in Azure (from ARM template or other way). If not - you can always use CLI or PowerShell to do so. More info: [az cli server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest)
2) Deploy the database or changes to it. This step is always to compare DACPAC file (which is compiled version of SQL Server database project) to target database on the server. The result is T-SQL (differential) script which must be executed against the target database. There is only one way to do so - `sqlpackage.exe` - tool provided by Microsoft. You can find the [whole documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage) and plenty of examples on how to use it on the Internet.
Let me know if that helps.